# Node.js transform stream only passes through data as-is

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I'm trying to create a little Node.js app that can read Markdown text and converts it to HTML. To achieve this, I wanted to create a transform stream that would get a char at a time, figure the meaning, then return the HTML version of it.

So, for example, if I pass the transform stream a *, it should return `<b>`(or `</b>`).

However, the Transform stream does not actually transform data, whatever I push to it, it just comes back like I pushed it, and when I put a `console.log` statement into the transform method of the stream, I saw no output, as if the method isn't even called.

Here's the file with the Stream:

```
module.exports = function returnStream() {

const Transform = require('stream').Transform;

let trckr = {
    bold: false
};

const compiler = new Transform({
    transform(chunk, encoding, done) {
        const input = chunk.toString();
        console.log(input); // No output
        let output;

        switch (input) {
          case '*':
            if (trckr.bold === true) {
              output = '</b>';
              trckr.bold = false;
            } else {
              output = '<b>';
              trckr.bold = true;
            }

            break;

        default:
            output = input;
    }

    done(null, output);
  }
});

  return compiler;

};
```

Example file that uses the Stream:

```
const transformS = require('./index.js')();

transformS.on('data', data => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

transformS.push('*');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`done(null, output)` and `transformS.push()` are performing the exact same function: they push data to the *readable* (the output) side of the Transform stream. What you need to do instead of calling `transformS.push()` is to write to the *writable* (the input) side of the Transform stream with `transformS.write('*')`.

I should also point out that you should not make assumptions about the contents of `chunk` in your transform function. It could be a single character or a bunch of characters (in which case `input` *may never* equal `'*'`).